# Silent authentication with Tomcat and Active Directory

Tags: tomcat, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect user logged on a computer using Java web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726249/detect-user-logged-on-a-computer-using-java-web-app)

I need to do that with tomcat and a J2EE Web App. I don't want a pop up window asking the user for credentials.

I must use the user logged on Windows to authenticate him on my web app.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: wow, I had the same question!

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267869 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343841

Comment: Not duplicate. More detailed question.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe Tomcat natively supports integrated authentication, however it does support custom authentication modules. Give these URL's a try:

http://appliedcrypto.com/files/tomcat_spnego.pdf

http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat doesn't support NTLM authentication, but there are other Java security libraries that do, such as Spring Security. Using SS, we have Tomcat and JBoss applications which silently authenticate against an MS Active Directory in both IE and FF browsers.

Here's a URL that might be helpful:
http://blog.mediasoft.be/ntlm-with-spring-security-20/