# Use Windows network domain authentication for web application hosted on solaris

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, solaris

I have a web application on solaris hosted on apache tomcat 6
I would like the login to my application happen using our windows network domain userneme/password, meaning I do not want to go for a separate authentication mechanism and separate username passwords. 
can someone please guide me how.

Comment: Links are considered bad form as an answer, I don't feel like typing all of this so visit: [solaris ldap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1455/adsetup-2.html)   This hows how to integrate authentication using your active directory server.

Answer (score 0):

The Active Directory server providing authentication services to your Windows network is just another LDAP server.

Tomcat supports LDAP authentication through the JNDI realm, which is documented at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm, without getting specific on Active Directory though. You'll need to figure out the correct configuration values yourself, I'm afraid.

You also may want to look at this StackOverflow question: [Configuring Tomcat to authenticate using Windows Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267869/configuring-tomcat-to-authenticate-using-windows-active-directory), which seems to be similar to yours.

Hope this helps!