# Tomcat 7 using windows authentication

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Hosting a site on tomcat7.
The hosted site (Activiti buisness process management) is REST API, When sending a GET i need to provide Header: Basic authentication key, I want the user running the Internet explorer to be authenticated automatically without providing the header.

I was reading the [Build-in tomcat support](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html#Built-in_Tomcat_support)  section, configured everything, but it is not working, there are no exceptions in tomcat logs, it seems like i am missing some crucial "TURN FEATURE ON" configuration.
From reading, I see that maybe i need to set up JaasRealm ? Or it is already setup by default in tomcat7?
If i need to set up spengo and jaasrealm, so what is the benefit of tomcat 7 vs 6 ? and why shouldnt i use easier package (e.g waffle) ?

How tomcat 7 implemented Windows authentication/Kerberos ?

Answer (score 0):

Th only Realm set up by default in Tomcat is the one that uses the highly insecure `users.xml` file. You need to specifically enable a JAAS realm, and to configure it to use the JAAAS NTLM provider.

Comment: When i am reading https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JAASRealm - Why i need to write code, i want to authenticate my domain controller active directory server,Am i missing something ? why should i implement a class, override methods, etc.. Thats what jaasrealm should do for me ? no ? we are all using the same protocol, only the credentials are different and they should be taken from the threads' credential

Comment: Why should i use jaas and not jndi realm as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267869/configuring-tomcat-to-authenticate-using-windows-active-directory?rq=1  - are the results the same ?