# Is there client side javascript code for retrieving AD information from the current user

Tags: javascript, active-directory, userid

I have an old ASP application that is being rewritten using Angularjs for the front end and java (tomcat) on the backend. The application will run on our intranet. The old code had an .asp page which returned the userid of the person accessing the page. The code looks like this.

```
<%
'  Get UserID of the user entering the webpage
IN_USRID = Request.ServerVariables("Auth_User")
response.write IN_USRID
response.write "<BR>"
%>
```

I can call this page from my current angular application and get the userid but that would mean I have to keep the IIS server up and running to support this one page after the the application has been rewritten.

Is there a way to retrieve this information using just the tomcat webserver?

Comment: You can't do this client-side.  Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267869/configuring-tomcat-to-authenticate-using-windows-active-directory) for possibilities server-side.

Comment: From the client now, I can make a call to the ASP page on the IIS server and get this information.  If possible, I want to be able to make the same call to a non IIS server.